# Access js file on second local server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 servers running one on port 80 and the other on port 8080.

In an html file (demo_audio_video_simple.html) on the port 80 server I have the following 2 lines of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/test.js"></script>
```

My test.js file is:

```
console.log("inside test.js");
```

When I run both programs and go to demo_audio_video_simple.html I get this in my console in my browser:

```
inside test.js  test.js:1:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8080/test.js”.
```

The script finds the file just fine on the program running on port 80 but can’t find it in the program running on port 8080. I’ve put the test.js file in every conceivable place I can think of on the port 8080 program, with the same results.

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: The file should be in the document root of the 8080 server. What does the server log say?

Comment: Is there an error code in the Network tab of the console?

Comment: can you access http://localhost:8080/test.js from your browser?

Comment: if you put a simple html there, does it open? (meaning 'is everything ok with the second server?')

Comment: I’m not sure what the server log is.

In the browser network console log it doesn’t show any errors, it just says 0 bytes transferred. It can’t find any of the other files (css,etc) on the 8080 local host either.

The program on 8080 is running. netstat -nlp shows listening on port 80. I’m on AWS, so the only way to see if it’s running in the browser is to create a load balancer. When I do this, the program shows in my browser. 

I’ve tried 2 really simple express servers with the same problem.

Do you think this is some sort of AWS constraint I’m dealing with?

Comment: correction "listening on port 8080"

Comment: SOLVED: answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193919/aws-first-server-access-files-on-second-server