# AWS first server access files on second server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am running an AWS ubuntu 16.04 nodejs EC2 instance. I have 2 basic express servers running on different ports.
I want to access files on the second server in an html in my first server.
This command in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:84/test.js"></script>
```

doesn’t work for some reason. I have put the test.js file in every conceivable spot.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my previous stackoverflow post that I’ve basically just reworded:

[Access js file on second local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183539/access-js-file-on-second-local-server)

This is my original post on the easyrtc forum when I initially tried to do the same thing in meteor:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/easyrtc/Mx48JcSpGwE

This is the reference of what I’m trying to eventually do:

https://easyrtc.com/docs/easyrtc_with_other_servers.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a few items from your question, but I'll take a guess as to what's happening.

You're getting your original request from some server via a browser.  The HTML that is returned includes the javascript link you have in your question above.

At this point, http://localhost/ is the machine the browser is running on, NOT the same server the original content came from.  So you will need to replace the localhost with the name or IP address of the server.

You'll also have to make sure that one of the security groups associated with the EC2 instance has a rule to allow port 84 in addition to port 80.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. But AWS instances only allow http access on port 80, which I'm already using. So I can't do it this way? But when you start a program that uses the mongo database they use "localhost". They must establish the connection in a server side js file? Which is what I need to do to implement what they're doing in my last easyrtc link?

Comment: You are in complete control of what ports are open - AWS does not limit this in any way.  "localhost" may work for mongo because it is running on the same instance, and it is the code running on the server that resolves the hostname - not your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use http or https

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:84/test.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED The answer Chris gave works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ec2-54...est-2.compute.amazonaws.com:84/test.js"></script>
```

I was thinking the security group rule had to be http, which forces you to use port 80, but a "custom TCP rule" on port 84 works fine. Thanks.